# How to write this query in django queryset? Find all topic_name for gaurd name = Algebra?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Defined Models Are... Gaurd(name, category) Chapter(Gaurd, Chapter, rates) and Topic(chapter, topic_name, level) These three are connected via foreign key with each other.

Comment: provide some actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you modify your questing and post some actual model classes along with any queries you have already tried.

Here is what the query might look like:

`Topic.objects.filter(chapter__guard__name='Algebra').values_list('topic_name', flat=True)`

Remove the `values(...)` call to get full topic objects.